# What is the temp velocity of Nichrome?

Tags: temperature, heat

I have read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nichrome) and [here](http://www.cecs.wright.edu/balloon/images/2/22/Nichrome_Wire_Heating_Element_Design_Basics.pdf) that nichrome of a certain gauge requires a certain amount of amps to reach a certain temp. e.g: 30awg nichrome requires 0.92Amps to reach 205 Degrees Centigrade. With 1 foot of 30awg wire. 12V will get the wire to 583 Degrees Centigrade.

Question: How long does it take to reach from room temp to the final temp? i.e. What is the temp velocity of Nichrome wire?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nichrome

Comment: Note that it's asymptotic, as the balance between energy put into the wire and energy radiated and convected away is reached. It will probably reach 90% of that temperature within a few seconds. What rate of heating do you actually require, and what are you heating?

Comment: If you put (and continue to put) power into a wire that is thermally insulated (and in a vacuum for good measure) it will eventually, I'm told, melt.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_constant#Thermal_time_constant

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple answer to this question.

In fact, the "final temperature" value is only an approximation, since it very strongly depends on the cooling characteristics of the wire and its environment.

The time constant you're looking for partly depends on how the rate of energy loss to the ambient environment varies with temperature, and partly depends on the mass and specific heat of the wire itself.

Comment: What kind of times can I expect in theory?

Comment: @kurtnelle "it very strongly depends on the cooling characteristics of the wire and its environment".  Theory won't free you from this reality; it will only predict values if you define the wire and its environment.